# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static filed method line 17 and 9

Tags: java

I am trying so save the input from the scanner but I keep getting cannot make a static reference

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Month {
        //instance fields
        int number;
        //constructor methods
        private String names;
        public Month(String names){
        names = ("January February March April May June July August September October November December");
        }
        //main method
        public static void main(String[]args){
          System.out.println("Enter number from 1 - 12: ");
          Scanner one = new Scanner (System.in);
            number=one.nextdouble();  
        }      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark `number` as `static`

`static int number;`

Comment: _Mark number as static_ because... ?